# Is there anyway to override methods when using templates?

Tags: java, templates

I need to have the same method but having different argument types :

```
public interface IKid<T,D,S> {

    public T findCookie(D id);

    public T findCookie(S id);  

}
```

So that I can do this while implementing this interface :

```
public class NaughtyKid implements IKid<Foo, Loo, Moo> {
    public Foo findCookie(Loo id);

    public Foo findCookie(Moo id);      
}
```

But, I get this error in the interface :

```
Method findCookie(D) has the same erasure findCookie(Object) as another method in type IKid<T,D,S>.
```

Is there anyway to avoid this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: What should happen if you have something like `public class NiceKid implements IKid<Integer, String, String>` and then you try to call `findCookie("chocolate")` - which method should be called?

Comment: @DavidWallace totally agree with you. I only wondered if there is a workaround.

Comment: Well, my point is, you need to make the declarations somehow different.  So you really need to _either_ supply an extra parameter, _or_ give the two methods different names.  It's not clear why you don't want to have different names for the methods - it seems to me to be the most obvious thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there anyway to avoid this problem?

You just need to provide different names for the methods - it's as simple as that.

Aside from anything else, that removes the obvious problem if you implement `IKid<Object, String, String>` and want to provide two different implementations for the two different *interface* methods which would have the same signature after type replacement.

It also makes it much easier to understand any code using the interface, as you'll be able to tell at a glance which method is being called without hunting down type arguments.